# Where is the current_thread_info implementation for x86_64?

Tags: linux, process, linux-kernel, scheduler

Inside a Linux Kernel git working directory I did:

`git grep -n '*current_thread_info('`

and nothing appear to come up related to x86_64. The outout was:

```
arch/arc/include/asm/thread_info.h:62:static inline __attribute_const__ struct thread_info *current_thread_info(void)
arch/arm/include/asm/thread_info.h:86:static inline struct thread_info *current_thread_info(void) __attribute_const__;
arch/arm/include/asm/thread_info.h:88:static inline struct thread_info *current_thread_info(void)
arch/c6x/include/asm/thread_info.h:62:struct thread_info *current_thread_info(void)
arch/csky/include/asm/thread_info.h:43:static inline struct thread_info *current_thread_info(void)
arch/h8300/include/asm/thread_info.h:50:static inline struct thread_info *current_thread_info(void)
arch/m68k/include/asm/thread_info.h:46:static inline struct thread_info *current_thread_info(void)
arch/microblaze/include/asm/thread_info.h:90:static inline struct thread_info *current_thread_info(void)
arch/mips/include/asm/thread_info.h:55:static inline struct thread_info *current_thread_info(void)
arch/nios2/include/asm/thread_info.h:67:static inline struct thread_info *current_thread_info(void)
arch/sh/include/asm/thread_info.h:70:static inline struct thread_info *current_thread_info(void)
arch/sparc/include/asm/thread_info_64.h:128:extern struct thread_info *current_thread_info(void);
arch/um/include/asm/thread_info.h:44:static inline struct thread_info *current_thread_info(void)
arch/unicore32/include/asm/thread_info.h:90:static inline struct thread_info *current_thread_info(void) __attribute_const__;
arch/unicore32/include/asm/thread_info.h:92:static inline struct thread_info *current_thread_info(void)
arch/xtensa/include/asm/thread_info.h:84:static inline struct thread_info *current_thread_info(void)
```

Any idea where to find the current_thread_info implementation for x86_64?

Answer (score 0):

I found it:

```
include/linux/thread_info.h
arch/x86/include/asm/current.h
```

Comment: LXR online service is useful to search functions and macro in linux kernel: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/ident/current_thread_info https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/thread_info.h#L22

Answer (score 0):

use current pointer to get info related to kernel thread currently running.
Ex: to print pid use printf("%d",current->pid);